# Android Studio app runs only after changing code

Tags: android

After starting to use Android Studio 2.0, when I open old projects first time executing "Run App" crashes app on Android device but when I comment out every code on MainActivity I can "Run App" without problem, then I just uncomment lines I've already commented and "Run App" again and it works flawlessly too...
So I need to do that three step after a while but as I said I only comment and uncomment code blocks, so eventually code that did not work at first time starts to run and I looked for logs before and after doing these, and before commenting there is only two log lines and then no output occurs in logcat

```
09-29 23:42:15.248 8328-8328/sparkgoattendance.bsobe.com.attendance I/art: Late-enabling -Xcheck:jni
09-29 23:42:15.439 8328-8328/sparkgoattendance.bsobe.com.attendance W/System: ClassLoader referenced unknown path: /data/app/sparkgoattendance.bsobe.com.attendance-1/lib/arm
```

and I get these log lines in logcat at top after doing commenting uncommenting thing, so I don't know if it is related to my problem.

I suspect it is a problem about ART and wait for your help, thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In **Run/Debug Configuration**, there is **Miscellaneous** tab. There is an option called **Skip installation if APK has not changed**. Uncheck that option.

It sounds like APK already existed and for some reason,it just installed that APK from before. If you uncheck it, it will create a new one each time.  This is why when you commented and uncommented the code, it worked. Because it created a new APK.

Comment: thank you so much it solved my problem, I cannot +1 because of lack of reputation